# Equal height columns with Bootstrap and child's height in percentage

Tags: html, css

I used this system to have 2 columns with same height, but I want the child to have percentage height. But it doesn't work.

http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/

This is my code:

```
<div class="row" style="display: flex;">
<div class="col-lg-6" style="background-color: blue;">1<br />2<br />3<br /></div>
<div class="col-lg-6" style="background-color: purple;">
    <div style="height: 50%; background-color: yellow;">I want this as 50% of father</div>
    <div style="height: 50%; background-color: orange;">I want this as 50% of father</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you give more detail on your specific problem? Can you please include some code that has the problem?

Comment: First thing post your code tried so far and second thing is it's not clear what you asking for.

Comment: Can you give us a working fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it by getting the height of the parent, dividing it by two and set the child height to the child to the new height using javascript like this: http://jsfiddle.net/1r4v8fcf/5/

```
function height() {
    var height = document.getElementById('fullHeight').clientHeight;
    height = height / 2;
    document.getElementById('halfHeight').style.height = height + "px";
}
```

You can test it by changing the height of this img place holder:

from: `<img src="http://placehold.it/100x400">`

to: `<img src="http://placehold.it/100x800">`